# docker does not installs the updated pipfile

Tags: python, django, docker, pipenv

I am using docker in my project. Initially there was following packages in Pipfile

```
[packages]
django = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
celery = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
redis = "*"
django-celery-beat = "*"
flower = "*"
django-environ = "*"
django-redis = "*"
"flake8" = "*"
coverage = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
sentry-sdk = "*"
django-storages = {extras = ["boto3"], version = "*"}
django-anymail = {extras = ["mailgun"], version = "*"}
pillow = "*"
"psycopg2-binary" = "*"
django-money = "*"
django-phonenumber-field = "*"
phonenumbers = "*"
"argon2-cffi" = "*"
jsonfield = "*"
future = "*"
django-contrib-comments = "*"
tzlocal = "*"

[dev-packages]
werkzeug = "*"
"autopep8" = "*"
"flake8" = "*"
```

I then build my project and it worked fine. But soon after building an image, i installed following packages in my local environment using

```
pipenv install pylint-django pylint-celery django-debug-toolbar django-extensions --dev
```

Now that i have updated my packages list, I tried to rebuild the image using `docker-compose -f local.yml build` which i guess did not installed those packages so I am getting issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'.

Here is my docker configuration

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client


RUN pip3 install -U pip pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --ignore-pipfile


COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

why it is not installing the new packages which are in Pipfile after already building an image?

Comment: you need add this  `RUN pipenv install pylint-django pylint-celery django-debug-toolbar django-extensions --dev` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: are you using the same python version in local and in the docker image?

Comment: yes same version.

Comment: @Adiii what if i again installed other 10 packages ? Do i have to again list those packages in Dockerfile? Won't it take update itself from Pipfile instead of adding packages in the command RUN pipenv install again and again?

Comment: yes you have list them in your Dockerfile

Comment: I've not sure if I understand you correctly... But if you need `debug_toolbar` package to run your application, shouldn't you add it into `packages` section instead of `dev-packages` section? As `dev-packages` won't be installed while deploying. You don't need to add it into the Dockerfile.

Comment: debug toolbar is only needed in local environment so i have added it into dev-packages.

Comment: Please @ me so I can get the notification. If it is only needed in the local environment, your application won't even need to import that module in production. Thus you don't need to install it and there won't be `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: @Sraw I am using docker for local environment as well.

Answer (score 0):

I smashed my head on this as well. Turns out it was a caching issue.

To resolve it, I ran the following command, but [*read what it does before you run it!*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

```
docker system prune -a
```